# Implementing a memoize-style module loader in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Began restructuring my Backbone app referencing this article by Bocoup: http://weblog.bocoup.com/organizing-your-backbone-js-application-with-modules

I'm having trouble initializing the views as defined in the module.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicksergeant/8L6JX/

My application.js:

```
// Memoizing technique from http://weblog.bocoup.com/organizing-your-backbone-js-application-with-modules
var sidepros = {
    // Create this closure to contain the cached modules
    module: function() {
        // Internal module cache.
        var modules = {};

        // Create a new module reference scaffold or load an
        // existing module.
        return function(name) {
            // If this module has already been created, return it.
            if (modules[name]) {
                return modules[name];
            }

            // Create a module and save it under this name
            return modules[name] = { Views: {} };
        };
    }()
};

// Using the jQuery ready event is excellent for ensuring all 
// code has been downloaded and evaluated and is ready to be 
// initialized. Treat this as your single entry point into the 
// application.
jQuery(function($) {

    if ($('body').hasClass('apply')) {
        sidepros.app = new sidepros.module('apply').Views.AppView();
    }

});
```

The module, apply.js:

```
(function(Apply) {

    App = sidepros.app;

    Apply.FieldModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        group: null
    });
    FieldView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.model = new FieldModel({
                group: $(this.el).parents('div.group').attr('id')
            });
            this.model.view = this;

            this.$tooltip = $('div.tooltip', $('#' + this.model.get('group')));
        },
        events: {
            'focus': 'focused',
            'blur' : 'blurred',
            'keyup': 'updateTooltip'
        },
        focused: function() {
            App.$tooltips.hide();
            this.$tooltip.show();
        },
        blurred: function() {
            App.$tooltips.hide();
        },
        updateTooltip: function() {
            if (this.model.get('group') == 'name') {
                short_name = $.trim(App.$first_name.val() + ' ' + App.$last_name.val().charAt(0));
                if (short_name !== '') {
                    short_name = ': ' + short_name;
                }
                App.$name_preview.text($.trim(short_name));
            }
        }
    });

    AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#app',

        initialize: function(opts) {
            $('input, select, textarea', this.el).each(this.addField);

            this.$first_name   = $('input#id_first_name', this.el);
            this.$last_name    = $('input#id_last_name', this.el);
            this.$name_preview = $('strong#name-preview', this.el);
            this.$tooltips     = $('div.tooltip', this.el);
        },
        addField: function() {
            model = new FieldView({ el: this });
        }
    });

    Apply.Views = {
        'AppView': AppView,
        'FieldView': FieldView
    };

})(sidepros.module('apply'));
```

When attempting to init the AppView like so:

```
sidepros.app = new sidepros.module('apply').Views.AppView();
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_configure'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because Javascript is getting confused about the context of your constructor function.  If you step into your `AppView` constructor, the context is `Apply.Views`, which means the `new` operator hasn't been called yet.

To get rid of that error, you need to do one of the following:

```
    var appView = sidepros.module('apply').Views.AppView;
    sidepros.app = new appView();
```

OR

```
    sidepros.app = new (sidepros.module('apply').Views.AppView)();
```

Beyond that, I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do.  There are no `input`, `select` or `textarea` nodes in your jsFiddle, so I can't say for sure what your next problem is.

In addition, this line `model = new FieldView({ el: this }):` feels really odd to me.  Why are you setting your model to your view in the `addField` function?

I think a new jsFiddle is necessary to debug further.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. You helped me understand how this situation works. Still trying to wrap my head around closures so this was where I was falling short. If you're interested, here's a working version of what I was trying to get at: http://jsfiddle.net/nicksergeant/8L6JX/6/